# Unknown custom element: <v-app> in Root when using vue with laravel

Tags: javascript, laravel, vue.js, vuetify.js

I am trying to use vue and vuetify with Laravel. I already have an vue component working fine without Vuetify. When I install `vuetify v1.5.1` and tried to use v-btn including v-app it gives me this errors in console.

[image: Errors]

I use these versions 
        `"stylus": "^0.54.5",`
        `"stylus-loader": "^3.0.2",`
        `"vue": "^2.6.6",`
        `"vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.6"`

app.js

```
require('./bootstrap');
import 'vuetify/dist/vuetify.min.css'
window.Vue = require('vue');
import Vuetify from 'vuetify'


Vue.component('example-component', 
require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue').default);

Vue.component('daily-delivery-planner', 
require('./components/DailyDeliveryPlanner.vue').default);

Vue.use(Vuetify);

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app'
});`
```

DailyDeliveryPlanner.vue

```
`<template>
<div class="page-content browse container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-bordered">
              <div class="panel-body">
                <div class="col-md-9">
                  <div class="form-group row">
                      <label for="day" class="col-sm-1 col-form-label custom-label">Select A Day</label>
                      <div class="col-sm-9">
                        <v-btn color="success">Success</v-btn>
                      </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3">
                  <div class="">
                      <h4>Route Plan Code : <span class="label label-info" id="routeplanno">{{ routeplan_no }}</span></h4>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
          </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

</template>

<script>
    export default {

        data() {
           return {
             routeplan_no: "",
          };
       },

       methods: {
        getUserData: function() {
            axios.get('retreiveUserData')
                .then(({data}) => {
                    if(data.alert=='success'){
                        this.routeplan_no = data.data;
                    }else{
                        this.routeplan_no = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
                    }
                });
        }
    },
    beforeMount() {
        this.getUserData();
    }
}
</script>`
```

functions and the everything work but the only problem is i can't use vuetify components.

browse.blade.php

```
@extends('voyager::master')

@section('content')
<v-app id="app">
    <daily-delivery-planner></daily-delivery-planner>
</v-app>

@endsection`
```

Why is it happening ? Any help would be appreciated !

Answer (score 2):

`v-app` has an id of `app`, which get initialized by `New Vue()`, and then you are initializing it as an component as well, so it gets initialized twice by Vue. Also, error also indicates that your Vue version is too low.